# Powershell missing terminator error

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I get an error when running a powershell script on one of our VMs. The error is:

```
ERROR: The string starting:
At C:\iso\floppy\Blah.ps1:7 
char:95
+ cinst VisualStudio2012Professional -packageParameters "/Features:'WebTools 
SQL VCMFCLibraries  <<<< ' " 
is missing the terminator: '.
```

The line, as pasted straight from the script is:

```
cinst VisualStudio2012Professional -packageParameters "/Features:'WebTools SQL VCMFCLibraries ' "
```

I can't see an error at all, the terminators are all correct, and this line was working fine until a few days ago.

Hoping someone else can see the obvious.

Comment: You've tried removing the trailing spaces in your string?  That is, `"/Features:'WebTools SQL VCMFCLibraries'"` instead of `"/Features:'WebTools SQL VCMFCLibraries ' "`?

Comment: Yes I have - I actually added those when it stopped working to see what happened. Makes no difference.

Comment: that string works fine for me, if you remove everything except for the string itself does it still error?

Comment: I'm thinking possibly a stranded quote somewhere else in the script.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any stray quotes **before** this string. It certainly looks very much like it.

Comment: Thanks all - I checked that I don't have stray quotes before my string and it doesn't appear that way - but I was modifying lines before that so it seems logical that it might be that. I'm trying removing some other lines to see if I can narrow down further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. Further up the script file I had added the line

```
choco sources add -n=Local -s='L:\Chocolatey Package Repository'
```

It should have been

```
choco sources add -n Local -s 'L:\Chocolatey Package Repository'
```

As well as being wrong, it turns out that the `=` screws up the quote parsing despite the fact that the quotes match up, leading to a weird error further down.

Thank you to everyone who commented, it helped.